# an emphatic pronoun between auxiliary verb and infinitive?

Tags: grammar

I know we can use an emphatic pronoun after the subject or at the end of the sentence. But I have found some examples from news websites where it has been used after an auxiliary verb and before the main verb. Is it grammatical at all? I haven't found anything about it in grammar books.

"He said his life was his art, but he didn't himself believe it."

Comment: I think 'I don't myself believe in such notions' is as grammatical as  'I myself don't believe in such notions'  and the less formal  'I don't believe in such notions myself'. Finding an authority to agree with this might present problems (not because any would necessarily disagree). / I'm not sure where @Jason has found the necessary corroboration of the relevant rule.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There is no such thing as something being *less* grammatical than something else. It's a binary choice. Something is grammatical or its ungrammatical. There are only degrees of stylistic acceptance for things that are grammatical. There is a large amount of discussion over the fact that SVO order, while common, is not the only grammatical way of structuring a sentence. This similarly applies to the reordering of other elements within that structure. Since this is only a comment, and I'm not going to provide a full answer, that's all I'll say about it here.

Comment: An unusual sentence it is, yet grammatical it remains. You can object to it on stylistic grounds if you wish, but it still follows syntactical rules. [This comment was deleted and reposted to correct a typo that was annoying me.]

Comment: @JasonBassford - Does it make any difference if I say "He didn't himself buy it" instead of "He himself didn't buy it"?

Comment: @TBY90 Not in terms of the essential meaning, no.

Comment: @JasonBassford So Svartvik has to bow to your superior knowledge. He actually says: 'The concept of ... grammaticality has considerable theoretical  and practical importance to the linguist. The problem is that sentences are not simply right or wrong, but often somewhere in between these two extremes....' (this because native speakers in well chosen usage panels could not always agree on the acceptability of sentences). Quirk in 'Investigating Linguistic Acceptability' and later Denison are others involved in research in this field.

Answer (score -1):

Intensive pronouns, also called emphatic pronouns, usually come immediately after the noun or pronoun they refer to, or at the end of a sentence.

For example: "He himself didn't believe it." "The doctors explained to the patient themselves."

In the book [Hart's Advanced Grammar](https://archive.org/details/advancedenglishg00hart/mode/2up) published in 1898, the author states the following:

> The intensive pronoun is always *in apposition* to the noun just
> before it, and is employed to make the noun more emphatic.
>
> ...
>
> The following examples will illustrate: The king *himself* will come
> (intensive)... I saw the queen *herself* (intensive).

Comment: Don't you think that your reference book is a bit old?!!